# How to submit form in embeded controller?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, submit, symfony-3.3

I want to make a newsletter in a footer with my service. To do that, I have to embed a controller in a view :

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:RegisterNewsletter:registerToTheNewsletter')) }}
```

The probleme is that when I submit my form, the page is refreshed but nothing else, even I insert a "die;"

```
public function registerToTheNewsletterAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('subscribe', SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        var_dump($data);
        die;
    }

    return $this->render('include/registerNewsletter.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution, when I said, I had to embed a controller in a view. In fact during the submitting, the page is refreshed and the data is lost.

So I change the action of the form to redirect the data on an other path, the data is processed in an other action and I redirect on the referer.

If you want more explains, ask me